# Time series analysis with 'missing values' in dependent variable

Tags: time-series, missing-data, finance

I am seeking to predict the price of a financial time series based on a number of features.

The price data of the dependent variable is obviously only available for trading days.

However, I have some variables that generate data every day. Over the weekend, these variables could then have 'jumps' if I were to only include the values that are on a trading day.

What are the best practices to deal with this issue?

Comment: You cannot do much here since you do not have $Y$ for a single non-trading day. To perform missing data imputation you need to have at least some information regarding the distribution of $Y$ on non-trading days. A popular approach on Wall Street is writing a model for trading days only but allowing the volatility of shocks (residuals) be higher on days following week-ends (Mondays typically).

Comment: Yes, I would not want to impute Y values for non trading days. I meant, what to do about the variables that have values on the weekends. But you're saying one method is to leave these values out?

Comment: Honestly, hard to say without seeing the data. This has to be decided after exploratory analysis. Potentially, the week-end variables could be used as predictors for volatility jumps on Mondays. Something of that sort: quantifying the verdict on whether the week-end was "crazy" (elections, hurricanes, terrorist attacks) or not.